# Eliminar cache, especialmente en chrome

Tags: html, cache, chrome

Una pregunta, alguno sabe como podría hacer que chrome no guarde tanto cache. 
Tengo que evitar que una imagen se quede congelada alrededor de 2 dias y despues cambia; pero en si la imagen al darle click ya sale la nueva y no puedo mover el link al que direcciona, pues no tengo acceso siempre al servido.
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola tendrías que especificarle al navegador cuales son los elementos que debe refrescar constantemente algo así quedaria tu .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 day"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 day"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: a que te refieres con "evitar que una imagen se quede congelada "

Comment: Congelada o no descargada por el navegador...debido a que la tiene almacenada en cache

Answer (score 0):

podrias evitar la carga de cache usando las etiquetas meta de html

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>

<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>

<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Otra forma es simular con javascript y jquery una funcion que simule presionar los 3 botones. 
cntrl+shift+suprimir para entrar en una nueva pestaña y presione el boton aceptar cada cierto tiempo despues de haber cargado tu archivo index